# Options for providing maps in a commercial, distributed application

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, openstreetmap

I'm looking for a way to supply a map (like Google Maps) in my commercially-distributed web application.  As far as I can tell, Google Maps doesn't give me what I need.  Here are my requirements:

1) Must not require my customers to procure and provide an API key

2) Must not be restricted to a URL or set of URLs (I have no idea where my customers will be using my application).

3) I don't care if it's a hosted solution, or if I need to bundle the mapping solution with my software.  I do need a JavaScript API.

I looked at a few OpenStreetMaps solutions .. but couldn't find one that allows me to do this.  I don't mind paying for this solution .. I don't need "free" ..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "distributed web application". Will you be hosting it for your customers or just providing it as a software package for your customers to host it themselves?

Anyway, there are a lot of ways of doing it with OpenStreetMaps, depending on whether you want the maps to come from the outside (internet) or hosted on the intranet. It also depends on whether you want to cover the whole world or just some smaller parts of it.

Some resources:

- http://switch2osm.org/
- http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map
- http://maperitive.net/ (disclaimer: I'm the author of Maperitive)

Comment: Sorry -- yeah -- I thought that might be confusing.  By distributed, I mean that it is not hosted.  We ship the web application (in VM and appliance form) to customers, so it's running all over the world.  Thanks - I'll check these out!